# USSD and balance checker on android 4.2?

Tags: android-4.2-jelly-bean, ussd

I want to develop an balance checker application on android?

Unfortunately, Android Jelly Bean 4.2 abandon USSD support. Do you know any way to support it on android 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: (replace 120 with your code of choice)

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
            String ussd = "*" + "120" + encodedHash;
            startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
            Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```